# Revert back to specific commit in Git

Tags: git, git-revert

On my Bitbucket Repo, I see this:

[image: repo]

I would like to get back to where I was when I made that commit with an arrow pointing to it.

In my commit where I removed AutoMapper, I removed many files and folders and I know want them all back. I want all to be same as before when I made the **44f31d5** commit.

I thought this would be common, so I tried all sorts from posts I found on SO (you can see my attempt) and this didn't work! I got that last commit by doing

```
git revert HEAD~1
```

And committing. I was thinking that would revert my last commit, instead I revert the second (if that makes sense).

Comment: The accepted answer is not the right one. `git revert HEAD~1` will revert the "second commit" like you mentioned in your question. The right way is `git revert HEAD`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, `git revert HEAD~1` will revert to your last commit, while if you want to revert to a specific commit, then use `git revert commit_id` or in your case you can also use `git revert HEAD~2` which will roll you back to previous two commits.

Comment: Note that `git revert commit_id` does NOT revert to that commit, but instead reverts what that specific commit did.

Comment: No, git reset changes the pointer, revert creates new commit.